# In SparkALS does 'Number of features' also mean 'Number of factors'?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm working through an early version of Spark ([alpha-0.1](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/alpha-0.1)) to understand how it started and how it has evolved.  I'm also trying to educate myself on how Alternating Least Squares works.

I'm looking through the SparkALS example and see the following variables:

```
  var M = 0 // Number of movies
  var U = 0 // Number of users
  var F = 0 // Number of features
```

*Source: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/alpha-0.1/src/examples/SparkALS.scala#L11-L13*

What does the F variable (Number of features) represent?

Can I interpret  this as the *Number of latent factors*?  This is also referred to as `rank` in the [Spark Collaborative Filtering documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html) page:

> rank is the number of latent factors in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the [Spark API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS$) refer to `rank` as the number of features:

> **rank** - number of features to use

So I guess the terminology **number of features** and **number of latent factors** *is* interchangeable.

Also see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20011